# Samba + active directory

Tags: active-directory, rsync, samba

I need to move from samba where users were created locally to a server where samba is in a domain. The new host is entered into the domain and fully configured, when running the id username command, everything is output correctly. Next I need to copy all files from the old server to the new one, I decided to use rsync rsync -varlHEpog --progress copying starts but for some reason on the remote server all directories get owner and root group
Who knows how to fix this error?

```
nsswitch.conf 
    passwd:         files winbind
    group:          files winbind
    shadow:         files winbind
    gshadow:        files winbind



krb5.conf
   default_realm = DOMEN.LOCAL

   [realms]
           DOMEN.LOCAL = {
                   kdc = pc.domen.local
                   admin_server = pc.domen.local
           }

   [domain_realm]
           .domen.local = DOMEN.LOCAL
            domen.local = DOMEN.LOCAL
```

I tried the following command, but it did not cause the directories to be created with the previous users and groups
rsync -varlHEpog --progress